# Removing a particular Javascript action from a responsive theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a responsive theme. When viewing the website on small screen, it shows "menu" and you have to tap it to see the menu items. What I want to do is show the menu items straight without the user having to tap "menu" before seeing them. I tried using Firebug to see what triggers it and tried removing that. But that messes up my whole site in desktop view as well.

Here is [the link](http://bit.ly/10NbZyU). If someone could point me in the right direction by telling me what code to remove that'd be great. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Search your code for zn_menu_trigger

Comment: thats what i tried at first ..i found its in line 2 but did not see actual part of code that triggers that function..removing the whole line messes up my whole site in desktop view,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is hidden via css. So to initially show that menu when the browser is mobile go into the bootstrap-responsive.css file on line :1424 and change 'display:none' to 'display:block'.  Just to be clear this is the code your looking for.

```
 nav#main_menu.smooth_menu ul {
   display: none;
   background:#fff; 
 }
```

It is in the @media (max-width: 767px) media query.

That should initially show the menu when a user is on a mobile browser while keeping the toggle functionality.

Comment: That would make both link and menu visible I would think

Comment: I guess I read his question to still allow the menu to toggle which you would still need the link.

Comment: wow,,it was through css and i was messing up with javascript the whole time lol.. thank you very much for the answer,,

Answer (score 0):

Add the below `<script>` in your page inside `<head>`. What it does is simulate a click on "menu" at startup.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.zn_menu_trigger a:visible').click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution..it does work but not the best practice..but i really appreciate your time for answering me though..